# Reflectometer - directional coupler

Tags: rf, reflection

I tried to use a single directional coupler to create a reflectometer and was hoping to measure both amplitude and phase of reflected signal.

My setup is a follows:

The directional coupler is from MiniCircuits ZFDC-10-182-S+

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbVPIr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have tested my design with different loads, 0R, 50R, 100R, 100R||3.3pF ect.

But only the magnitude (VMAG) measurements are correct, the phase (VPHS) measurements does not seems to be correct. And I cannot find any relation, between different loads and expected vs. measured phase.

So should it possible to measure phase information with a directional coupler?

Or am I doing it wrong ?

My measurement:

50R:  VPHS=0.88V,  VMAG=0.16V

**Open: VPHS=1.500V,  VMAG=0.76V**

Short: VPHS=0.282V,  VMAG=0.69V

100R: VPHS=1.455V,  VMAG=0.50V

100R||10pF: VPHS=0.58V,  VMAG=0.66V

100R||3.3pF: VPHS=1.18V,  VMAG=0.57V

Edit: My open load now seems correct, before I measured open load as "no load" in the cable, but this resulted in a capacitance in the cable end SMA connector. I have now made an open load as an trimmed down SMA connector. I still don't get why the magnitude i higher, but that is maybe related to the load on the source being changed.

Comment: It would be useful to show your measured data. Also to show what you're measuring when the load is a short and an open circuit.

Comment: Ok, I have added measurements now.

Comment: Did you consider in your calculations the effect on a phase that connection cables are giving? If possible, show how you calculated the expected phase.

Comment: The phase when having an open circuit and when having 100 ohms resistor should be the same. The connection length between the IN port and those two loads (100R and the open circuit) is the same?

Comment: I used the same 0.75m cable with SMA connectors. I assumed that the phase added by the cable would be constant, when the frequency was constant. And therefore when comparing the measurements, the phase difference between them should match the calculated. That is the phase error is just an offset, or am I wrong?

Comment: It seems to me that the dynamic range of phase output for ad8302 is 143 degrees. The phase difference for open and short must be 180 degrees. Vmag for open and short must be equal. Are you using standard open and short termination plugs suitable for your frequency?

Comment: I'm just using a SMA connector with end soldered shorted and nothing for open. So probebly not optimum, but how about the 100R and 100R || 3.3pF etc. Should they not match the theory, at least within say 20-30 degrees. I'm not trying to measure very accurate, but I expected some relation between measured an theory.

Comment: For a proper measurement I would recommend using standard open and short termination plugs suitable for UHF band. Something like [this](http://www.keysight.com/en/pd-1000003537%3Aepsg%3Apro-pn-85032F/standard-mechanical-calibration-kit-dc-to-9-ghz-type-n-50-ohm?nid=-32574.536880667&cc=US&lc=eng). What you are using now is more like different types of antenna to me.

Comment: Sorry, the phase difference would be close to theoretical with 3.3pf in series with 100R, not in parallel. How you created this load?

Comment: I just soldered a 0603 resistor and capacior to an SMA connector. With very short leads <1mm. Sorry, but why is the parallel 100R and 3.3pF not a good load ?

Comment: @JakobJ maybe your measurements are coherent because you're not using calibrated loads. If you have for example 1 cm length (0.5 cm each way) difference between two configurations (100R and Open) this will translate to a phase offset (that might be big depending on your working frequency). At 2 GHz 1 cm implies 24º offset. At what frequency are you working? Ups! 868 MHz, should had read the diagram.

Comment: @JakobJ I just calculated phase difference between 100R and 100R || 3.3pF loads and between 100R and 100R with 3.3pF in series loads. The last one is very close to your measurement results. Try to measure on much lower frequency, say 50 MHz. If you get reasonable results than this is all about your measurement setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing a few calculations it seems to me that your measurements are correct. Let's take for example:

$$ 100R//10 pF = (@ 868 MHz) = 3.25-17.7j $$
Then if we calculate the reflection coefficient:
$$ \rho=\frac {Z_L-Z_0} {Z_L+Z_0} =-0.69 -0.56 j$$
The phase of \$\rho\$ is -141º=219º. In comparison the phase of \$\rho\$ for a 100R load is 0º.

In your measurements with 100R//10pF you have 0.58 V -> \$\pm 58º\$ and with 100R you have 1.455 V -> \$\pm 145.5º\$. The \$\pm \$ accounts for the phase sign ambiguity of the used detector. Therefore the absolute phase difference is either \$145.5-58º=87º\$ or \$145.5+58º=203º\$, (we can't know which one to take because of the measurement phase ambiguity). We note that \$203º\$ and \$219º\$ are close enough.

If we repeat for 100R//3.3 pF we have that the phase of \$\rho\$ is \$-92º=268º\$. According to your measurements the phase difference between 100R//3.3pF and 100R is either \$145.5-118=27.5º\$ or \$145.5+118=263.5º\$ and \$263.5º\$ is quite close to \$268º\$.

Comment: Taking into account phase sign ambiguity, everything solves perfectly. I suppose with lower frequency OP will get 99% match.

Comment: I tried for many hours to make sense of my measurements, so now it finally makes sense. I think two factors was into play. 1) I used the short circuit as a base for my calculations, which was probably not an ideal short. 2) As pointed out by @ivan, the dynamic range of the AD8302 is 143 degrees, so it is not possible to span the range from short to open load.

Comment: @JakobJ 1) Actually your short looks good: 0.28 V could be -28º degrees (minus 28º) and when the load is 100R you have 146º. The phase difference is therefore 28+146=174º (almost the 180º as it should). 2) I've checked the datasheet and the phase range of the AD8302 is 180º (but with the sign ambiguity!). 3) It seems to me that the only load that should be checked is the "open" one, it should have the same phase than the 100R one (but somehow the reference plane for both loads is not the same).

Comment: @RogerC. you are right. If I do the calculations with the short as reference, I get same or even little better results. I think what actually helped me a lot, was your conversion to absolute degrees (0-360), the +/-180 degree is very confusing, when trying to compare results.

Comment: @RogerC could you point to the place in the datasheet where it says that the phase range of AD8302 is 180º?

Comment: @ivan, sure, if we take this datasheet http://www.analog.com/media/cn/technical-documentation/evaluation-documentation/AD8302.pdf, you can read in the first page "phase over a 0°–180° range scaled to 10 mV/degree". In page 2 you can see that 180º has an output of 30 mV and 0º has an output of 1.8 V, the phase-voltage relationship is therefore reverted. (I actually made my calculations by using 0º is 0V and 180º is 1.8 V, but because of the phase sign ambiguity you would get the same results).

Comment: What about Dynamic Range value on page 2?

Comment: @ivan this is about the linearity on the phase to voltage conversion. It gets less linear when approaching either 0º or 180º. You can see this graphically in figure TPC25. The behaviour at 868 MHz is actually rather good, it gets worst at higher frequencies.

Comment: If this non-linearity was taken into account when going back from voltage to phase we'd get more accurate results of course.

Comment: So, I get the measurements become less and less accurate after 145 degrees and this parameter sets a usable range (Less than ±1 Degree Deviation).

Comment: In other words, AD8302 can measure in 180 degree range and measure accurately in 145 degree range (less on higher frequencies).

Comment: @ivan, if you look carefully at TPC25 in http://www.analog.com/media/cn/technical-documentation/evaluation-documentation/AD8302.pdf you'll see that even for higher frequencies response is a line from about 20º to 160º. This is where the so called "dynamic range" of 145º comes from. In the other hand the response for 900 MHz is almost a line from about 10º up to 180º. The "dynamic range" would be 170º. The 145º is then a worst case figure. A part from this you are right the AD8302 can measure 180º degree phase range but the better accuracy is achievable in this smaller range.

Comment: @ivan, I must correct my previous comment. My graphical estimation of the "dynamic range" yields to a more optimistic result than calculating the "dynamic range" using the 1 dB deviation criteria. Your previous comment is therefore completely true :-).